# CSS - Moving buttons below existing div

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to move the buttons as listed below to the bottom of my page, below another div (which is essentially a large table) and the below html is outside of said div class but I'm actually stumped as to where I'm going so terribly wrong...

HTML

```
<div class="functions"> 
<button><a href= "#" id="donwload-link" onClick="save()">Save File</a></button>
<input id="fileInput" type="file" style="display:none;" />
 <button type="button" cmd>PDF</button> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
functions{
position:absolute;
bottom: 5%;
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly show us a sample image of what you want the final outcome to look like?

Answer (score 1):

In order to select a class with CSS, you have to put a period in front the variable.

Try:

```
.functions{
position:absolute;
bottom: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your CSS.

```
functions{
```

Should be

```
.functions{
```